# How to parse content of a SQL Server 2005 .MDF file?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, parsing

How to parse the content of a SQL Server 2005 `.mdf` file?

I need to extract all the stored procedures defined there. OrcaMDF fails on that file :(

Comment: One word: **DON'T** (even try....) - a `.mdf` file needs to be attached to a SQL Server instance before you can use it.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What is your task you want to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

[OrcaMDF](https://github.com/improvedk/OrcaMDF) is an interesting, but purely experimental project. The only way to inspect content of SQL Server databases ( the .MDF  and .LDF pair) is to attach them to a SQL Server instance and run T-SQL queries on it.